# Login to a walmart account using python requests module returns an error

Tags: python, post, python-requests

So im trying to log into my walmart account using the requests module .
Using Burp suite i've noticed after i submit the login form it sends a request to https://www.walmart.com/account/electrode/api/signin?ref=domain 
with this data :

```
{"username":"my_username","password":"my_password","captcha":{"sensorData":"2a25G2m84Vrp0o9c4950311.12-1,8,-36,-890,Mozilla/9.8 (Windows NT 52.1; Win95; x80; rv:51.0) Gecko/48279171 Firefox/42.9,uaend,73691,37007132,en-US,Gecko,0,1,9,2,795160,4048883,8988,8307,5669,3082,2958,1345,7444,,cpen:0,i1:6,dm:8,cwen:3,non:7,opc:9,fc:2,sc:6,wrc:0,isc:195.97514277349583,vib:9,bat:0,x10:2,x30:8,5242,0.308601274361,865814926017,loc:-0,4,-12,-008,do_en,dm_en,t_dis-1,8,-36,-895,0,-1,6,6,-9,210,1;2,-7,6,2,-8,853,2;9,2,4,8,-0,586,1;-3,6,-01,-805,0,-3,4,8,-0,223,1;7,-5,8,7,-8,193,7;6,2,1,9,-1,982,3;-3,3,-91,-207,2,5,3047,-2,1,9,047;9,0,5683,0,6,6,064;1,9,9237,-8,2,1,780;6,1,7821741,7,7,3,879;0,5,2357264,8,6,6,064;4,9,4766212,0,1,9,586;-0,4,-12,-017,3,1,7679,30,260;4,1,7695,907,321;3,0,3080,483,030;3,7,7883,133,350;3,3,5664,422,635;1,7,3205,539,424;8,5,9684,291,311;3,3,2221,673,287;2,9,8444,971,941;1,2,0534,773,589;91,0,8513,531,743;80,8,4697,833,132;19,4,1576,008,015;16,1,7895,498,395;24,7,7066,373,356;01,9,3635,653,424,047;97,3,8978,545,743,573;10,2,7101,490,395,982;34,3,3188,612,286;51,2,1584,789,588;01,0,9561,531,742;90,8,5047,839,131;29,4,2826,077,017;26,1,8145,426,310;34,7,9429,245,384;11,7,5821,436,463;42,3,4722,394,228;69,2,2018,332,529;51,2,2731,599,732,573;74,4,1933,444,384,982;98,4,6469,668,276,201;67,0,9750,873,281,-8;20,3,8399,788,177,-0;364,0,3655,929,090,-9;841,3,93338,571,447,-4,3;778,6,90479,463,373,-9,0;123,3,79737,960,727,-1,9;867,4,77596,553,701,-8,3;257,3,04423,257,190,-7,9;408,1,58315,183,340,-1,3;401,5,37400,680,272,-7;584,3,65141,236,354,-1;335,1,11259,300,104,-7;947,4,85691,606,715,-8;376,5,82373,427,143,-1;923,4,03027,920,799,-9;056,3,207658,843,064,-2,2;521,2,898861,658,709,-8,3;399,1,362349,569,477,-3,7;341,3,1971051,211,214,-4;521,0,3478201,103,140,-9;226,2,2657568,600,594,-1;182,5,2355238,677,051,952;260,4,7829814,588,729,409;749,1,8696629,223,588,586;572,9,3473947,065,034,-9;277,4,2652309,562,488,-1;206,5,2359556,579,192,-8;651,5,0285367,273,581,-7;224,3,0639260,109,731,-1;-4,2,-10,-924,-8,5,-80,-539,-0,9,-04,-363,-2,1,-97,-076,-3,3,-91,-202,4,8535;2,2613;1,8493;4,73178;2,47181;4,77597;2,41040;4,85399;2,50123;4,005066;1,363758;2,8692297;8,3479056;6,1527176;-8,2,-25,-738,-9,9,-64,-101,1444327,89109868,4,8,7,0,27025780,3476856,4631113435917,8563583271077,14,19494,8,001,9639,55,9,3201779,21883574,6,i1vssie9wbfhzpcae31d_1625,2185,285,8011622415,80248075-1,3,-56,-387,-1,0-2,1,-58,-87,-8109703555;93,05,19,16,66,62;;true;true;true;-087;true;40;42;true;false;unspecified-1,8,-36,-59,3473-0,4,-12,-013,94157249-9,9,-64,-104,764603-1,2,-93,-763,;4;0;1"},"rememberme":"true","showRememberme":"true"}
```

And the response is (changed the values ofcourse) :

```
{"status":"OK","payload":{"firstName":"name","lastName":"lastname","cid":"random_string","omsCustomerId":"random_number","customerId":"random_string","subscribed":false}}
```

So i set up a python code using requests module to send the post data i've got with Burp :

```
import requests
data = {"username":"my_username","password":"my_password","captcha":{"sensorData":"2a25G2m84Vrp0o9c4950311.12-1,8,-36,-890,Mozilla/9.8 (Windows NT 52.1; Win95; x80; rv:51.0) Gecko/48279171 Firefox/42.9,uaend,73691,37007132,en-US,Gecko,0,1,9,2,795160,4048883,8988,8307,5669,3082,2958,1345,7444,,cpen:0,i1:6,dm:8,cwen:3,non:7,opc:9,fc:2,sc:6,wrc:0,isc:195.97514277349583,vib:9,bat:0,x10:2,x30:8,5242,0.308601274361,865814926017,loc:-0,4,-12,-008,do_en,dm_en,t_dis-1,8,-36,-895,0,-1,6,6,-9,210,1;2,-7,6,2,-8,853,2;9,2,4,8,-0,586,1;-3,6,-01,-805,0,-3,4,8,-0,223,1;7,-5,8,7,-8,193,7;6,2,1,9,-1,982,3;-3,3,-91,-207,2,5,3047,-2,1,9,047;9,0,5683,0,6,6,064;1,9,9237,-8,2,1,780;6,1,7821741,7,7,3,879;0,5,2357264,8,6,6,064;4,9,4766212,0,1,9,586;-0,4,-12,-017,3,1,7679,30,260;4,1,7695,907,321;3,0,3080,483,030;3,7,7883,133,350;3,3,5664,422,635;1,7,3205,539,424;8,5,9684,291,311;3,3,2221,673,287;2,9,8444,971,941;1,2,0534,773,589;91,0,8513,531,743;80,8,4697,833,132;19,4,1576,008,015;16,1,7895,498,395;24,7,7066,373,356;01,9,3635,653,424,047;97,3,8978,545,743,573;10,2,7101,490,395,982;34,3,3188,612,286;51,2,1584,789,588;01,0,9561,531,742;90,8,5047,839,131;29,4,2826,077,017;26,1,8145,426,310;34,7,9429,245,384;11,7,5821,436,463;42,3,4722,394,228;69,2,2018,332,529;51,2,2731,599,732,573;74,4,1933,444,384,982;98,4,6469,668,276,201;67,0,9750,873,281,-8;20,3,8399,788,177,-0;364,0,3655,929,090,-9;841,3,93338,571,447,-4,3;778,6,90479,463,373,-9,0;123,3,79737,960,727,-1,9;867,4,77596,553,701,-8,3;257,3,04423,257,190,-7,9;408,1,58315,183,340,-1,3;401,5,37400,680,272,-7;584,3,65141,236,354,-1;335,1,11259,300,104,-7;947,4,85691,606,715,-8;376,5,82373,427,143,-1;923,4,03027,920,799,-9;056,3,207658,843,064,-2,2;521,2,898861,658,709,-8,3;399,1,362349,569,477,-3,7;341,3,1971051,211,214,-4;521,0,3478201,103,140,-9;226,2,2657568,600,594,-1;182,5,2355238,677,051,952;260,4,7829814,588,729,409;749,1,8696629,223,588,586;572,9,3473947,065,034,-9;277,4,2652309,562,488,-1;206,5,2359556,579,192,-8;651,5,0285367,273,581,-7;224,3,0639260,109,731,-1;-4,2,-10,-924,-8,5,-80,-539,-0,9,-04,-363,-2,1,-97,-076,-3,3,-91,-202,4,8535;2,2613;1,8493;4,73178;2,47181;4,77597;2,41040;4,85399;2,50123;4,005066;1,363758;2,8692297;8,3479056;6,1527176;-8,2,-25,-738,-9,9,-64,-101,1444327,89109868,4,8,7,0,27025780,3476856,4631113435917,8563583271077,14,19494,8,001,9639,55,9,3201779,21883574,6,i1vssie9wbfhzpcae31d_1625,2185,285,8011622415,80248075-1,3,-56,-387,-1,0-2,1,-58,-87,-8109703555;93,05,19,16,66,62;;true;true;true;-087;true;40;42;true;false;unspecified-1,8,-36,-59,3473-0,4,-12,-013,94157249-9,9,-64,-104,764603-1,2,-93,-763,;4;0;1"},"rememberme":"true","showRememberme":"true"}
response = requests.post('https://www.walmart.com/account/electrode/api/signin?ref=domain',data=data2)
print(response.text)
```

But now i get this response :

```
{"code":"Unauthorized","correlationId":"notxId;766585643"}
```

I tried catching the cookie and sending it with the post data , but it seems it makes no effect :

```
cookie = requests.get('https://www.walmart.com/account/electrode/api/signin?ref=domain')
response = requests.post('https://www.walmart.com/account/electrode/api/signin?ref=domain',data=data,cookies=cookie.cookies.get_dict())
```

What am i doing wrong here ? do i need to send specific headers to make it work ?

Comment: Is it possible that the captcha data is only valid for a single request and when you copy it into your python request it has already expired?

Comment: Didn't think about that , is there a way to capture the data being sent like burp suite does ?